# How to send emails with Phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

What is the best and most convinient way to send emails using Phoenix framework?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best way I've found is to use the [mailman](https://github.com/kamilc/mailman) package. For sending test emails I was using my gmail account using the following config for `mailman` ->

```
def config do
  %Mailman.Context{
   config: %Mailman.SmtpConfig{ relay: "smtp.gmail.com",                 
                                port: 587,
                                username: "myusername@gmail.com",
                                password: "mypassword",
                                tls: :always },                                            
   composer: %Mailman.EexComposeConfig{}
  }
end
```

and for the email content I was using the following:

```
def testing_email do
    %Mailman.Email{
      subject: "Hello Mailman!",
      from: "myusername@gmail.com",
      to: ["myotherusername@gmail.com"],          
      text: "Hello Mate",
      html: Phoenix.View.render_to_string(MyApp.PageView,"index.html", foo: "bar")
      }
end
```

and then you just do ->

1) `email = MyApp.Mailer.deliver testing_email`

2) `Task.await(email)`

Comment: There is not a lot of information on the subject so I decided to post the result of my efforts. Hopefully it'll be useful for anybody

Comment: Also it's possible to send emails using a package for mailgun API -> https://github.com/chrismccord/mailgun

Comment: I'm trying to use your code to send emails but Task.await eventually times out?

Comment: I would also recommend using `swoosh` package which seems like a good alternative.

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Bamboo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bamboo) — it is an excellent library with great documentation, comes with adapters for SendGrid and Mandrill, and features a handy way to preview emails sent locally in development mode. It works great with Phoenix and has support for rendering templates, too.

Comment: I think there was one thing about Bamboo that pushed me away is that they have reimplemented the smtp client in `bamboo_smtp` and I don't know how reliable that is.

Answer (score 5):

After trying a few, I'll definitely go with the https://github.com/swoosh/swoosh package. It has the best [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/swoosh/Swoosh.html), testing support, mailbox preview in the browser and the star count points to a greater amount of users.